# How do I change the calendar dot color on iPhone iOS 4?

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change a calendar’s color in iOS 4.2.1?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7847/how-do-i-change-a-calendars-color-in-ios-4-2-1)

It seems like it just assigns random color when you add a calendar.

Is there a way to change calendar color on iOS 4? I'd like to pick a color for each calendar...

Comment: Here's your answer: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27747/how-to-change-the-colors-of-calendars-on-ios5

Comment: Normally we close down to the oldest question, but in this case iOS 4 was hard to manage colors, iOS 5 got better and it's not an issue on iOS 6 as things now just work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know how to do it is in iCal (providing you have a Mac). Ctrl+click on the Calendar along the left side of the screen >> Get Info >> Click the color selector on the right to change the color. Here's a screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It seems impossible directly on the iPhone/iPod. I have a MobileMe account, and I can change the calendar colours from within the MobileMe web interface. Maybe this is possible with other snychable calendars (Google, Outlook, iCal), too. But I have none of them to try it.

Comment: I sync with Google Calendar using Exchange. The color on Google Cal does not transfer over to iPhone cal.

Comment: That's a pity. Just tried it with MobileMe, and it worked. Too bad that it is not for free.